# How to generate a JSON file using JMeter Report Generator

Tags: json, jmeter, exporter, reportgenerator

I am trying to create a statistics.json file with JMeter using ReportGenerator, populated with the results of my .jmx tests. Is it possible to do this with JMeter?

I have gone through this tutorial: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html which focuses on creating an html dashboard using the Report Generator, but I have a project requirement of creating/updating a statstics.json file as well. I have already pulled the necessary data using a JSON Extractor post processor, and I can get the custom variables from that extractor to show up in my debug response, and in my CSV file (after adding some sample_variables to user.properties). Unfortunately I have been unsuccessful in finding more info about how to create a JSON file with these responses.

In my reportgenerator.properties file, the only parts I see that relate to json are:

```
jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.json.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.JsonExporter
jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.json.property.output_dir=report-output
```

I'm looking for some settings that would allow me to edit what goes into that JSON file, but I'm having trouble finding information in the docs. Do I need to be sending or setting my custom variables in another settings file? Any help clarifying this would be much appreciated!

Comment: The accepted answer is correct. However, I'd like to add that I was able to complete my requirement by using a JSR223 post processor to write a groovy script that created csv file and filled it with any data that I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [JMeter source code](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/report/dashboard/JsonExporter.java#L118) you cannot efficiently control what's being exported into statistics.json file externally, you will have to either amend the JsonExporter class code or come up with your own implementation of the [AbstractDataExporter](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/079404a06a9b26b38e33900e0c6dc294ec3775df/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/report/dashboard/AbstractDataExporter.java#L30) and choose what, where and how to store.

```
private void createStatistic(Map<String, SamplingStatistic> statistics, MapResultData resultData) {
    LOGGER.debug("Creating statistics for result data:{}", resultData);
    SamplingStatistic statistic = new SamplingStatistic();
    ListResultData listResultData = (ListResultData) resultData.getResult("data");
    statistic.setTransaction((String) ((ValueResultData)listResultData.get(0)).getValue());
    statistic.setSampleCount((Long) ((ValueResultData)listResultData.get(1)).getValue());
    statistic.setErrorCount((Long) ((ValueResultData)listResultData.get(2)).getValue());
    statistic.setErrorPct(((Double) ((ValueResultData)listResultData.get(3)).getValue()).floatValue());
    statistic.setMeanResTime((Double) ((ValueResultData)listResultData.get(4)).getValue());
    statistic.setMinResTime((Long) ((ValueResultData)listResultData.get(5)).getValue());
    statistic.setMaxResTime((Long) ((ValueResultData)listResultData.get(6)).getValue());
    statistic.setMedianResTime((Double) ((ValueResultData)listResultData.get(7)).getValue());
    statistic.setPct1ResTime((Double) ((ValueResultData)listResultData.get(8)).getValue());
    statistic.setPct2ResTime((Double) ((ValueResultData)listResultData.get(9)).getValue());
    statistic.setPct3ResTime((Double) ((ValueResultData)listResultData.get(10)).getValue());
    statistic.setThroughput((Double) ((ValueResultData)listResultData.get(11)).getValue());
    statistic.setReceivedKBytesPerSec((Double) ((ValueResultData)listResultData.get(12)).getValue());
    statistic.setSentKBytesPerSec((Double) ((ValueResultData)listResultData.get(13)).getValue());
    statistics.put(statistic.getTransaction(), statistic);
}
```

An easier option would be writing your sample variables into a separate file using [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/)

Comment: This is super helpful thank you! Looking into Flexible File Writer now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm leaving the accepted answer because it is correct. However, I'd like to add that I was able to complete my requirement by using a JSR223 post processor to write a groovy script that creates a csv file wherever I need, and fill it with any data that I needed.